YOLOv8 - Noisy tracking data (python)
I have a physical device that can track objects according to their location on the screen. the location is given by YOLO detection.
As far a I know, YOLO is not dedicated for tracking. That’s why it uses external trackers such as BoT-Sort and bytetrack.
If I’m giving the physical device the location of the object based on the center of the detection bounding box it is very noisy because the size of the bounding box constantly changes.
Is it possible to get the location of the object directly from the tracker?
If not, I will appreciate it if you suggest me some methods to reduce the noise (Other than moving average :D)

You could try using a Kalman filter.
